# Get an error when trying to insert a table valued parameter

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Here's the Error:

> "The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC)
>   protocol stream is incorrect. Table-valued parameter 16
>   ("@InsertRateDetials"), row 0, column 0: Data type 0xF3 (user-defined
>   table type) has a non-zero length database name specified. Database
>   name is not allowed with a table-valued parameter, only schema name
>   and type name are valid."

```
 private void Build()
        {
            SqlParameter[] parameters =
                {
                    new SqlParameter( "@libLimitationID"    , LibLimitation.LibLimitationID),
                    new SqlParameter( "@admSectionId"       , LibLimitation.Section.SectionID),
                    new SqlParameter( "@libMARCFrameworkID" , LibLimitation.MARCFramework.LibMARCFrameworkID),
                    new SqlParameter( "@admPatronTypeID"    , LibLimitation.PatronType.admPatronTypeID),
                    new SqlParameter( "@ResLimit"           , LibLimitation.ResLimit),
                    new SqlParameter( "@RenLimit"           , LibLimitation.RenLimit),
                    new SqlParameter( "@LoanPeroid"         , LibLimitation.LoanPeriod),
                    new SqlParameter( "@LoanLimit"          , LibLimitation.LoanLimit),
                    new SqlParameter( "@Fine"               , LibLimitation.Fine),
                    new SqlParameter( "@DateEffective"      , LibLimitation.DateEffective),
                    new SqlParameter( "@InsertedUserID"     , LibLimitation.InsertedUserID),
                    new SqlParameter( "@DateInsert"         , LibLimitation.DateInsert),
                    new SqlParameter( "@UpdatedUserID"      , LibLimitation.UpdatedUserID),
                    new SqlParameter( "@DateUpdate"         , LibLimitation.DateUpdate),
                    new SqlParameter( "@RenPeriod"          , LibLimitation.RenewalPeriod),
                    new SqlParameter( "@InsertRateDetials" , LibLimitation.RateDetails)
                };

            Parameters = parameters;
        }
```

Above is the list of parameters I'm trying to pass to my stored procedure. The error is caused by the last line which is,

```
new SqlParameter( "@InsertRateDetials" , LibLimitation.RateDetails)
```

**RateDetails** is a DataTable.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Can u show some code ?

Comment: What is type of `LibLimitation.RateDetails` and `@InsertRateDetials` ?

Comment: LibLimitation.RateDetails-is the datatable that i;m passing to the stored procedure as a table valued parameter.
@InsertRateDetials- is the parameter which i'm using to access the user-defined type in my stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we provide DbType of SqlParameter for a normal parameter like varchar, nvarchar, int and so on as in the following code.

**Example:**

```
SqlParameter sqlParam= new SqlParameter();  
sqlParam.ParameterName = "@StudentName";  
sqlParam.DbType = DbType.String;  
sqlParam.Value = StudentName;
```

But in the case of a Table parameter, we do not need to provide a DbType as the parameter data type. We need to provide SqlType rather then DbType.

**Example:**

```
SqlParameter Parameter = new SqlParameter;  
Parameter.ParameterName = "@PhoneBook";  
Parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;  
Parameter.Value = PhoneTable;
```

More Details: [Refer this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/passing-datatable-to-storeprocedure-as-parameter-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: @Malika: Welcome.Mark it as answer.